# Run library build from app gradle as build.dependsOn libraryBuild task without including as dependency in app gradle file

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

In my case when I will run this below command

```
 ./gradlew -q projects
```

**It will return output as below**

---

### Root project

```
Root project 'MyProject'
+--- Project ':app'
\--- Project ':mymodule'
```

now I want to build(Run/Green Play icon for the app) my `':app'` so `':mymodule'` should build automatically 
but without including the `':mymodule'` as a dependency in `':app'` level build.gradle

something like this in app level build.gradle file

```
task gradleBuild(type: GradleBuild ) {
    println "gradleBuild task start"
    doFirst{
        tasks=["mymodule:clean"]
        tasks = ["mymodule:build"]
    }
    doLast {
        tasks = ["mymodule:install"]
        println 'gradleBuild task end.'
    }

}

build.dependsOn gradleBuild
```

But it not working I am getting the error message as below

```
Task :app:gradleBuild FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'mymodule' not found in project ':MyProject:app'.
```

In `settings.gradle` I have this

```
include ':app' , ':mymodule'
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this point -> now I want to build my ':app' so ':mymodule' should build automatically but without including the ':mymodule' as a dependency in ':app' level build.gradle

Comment: hi @BABASHANKER by build  i mean the Run/Green play icon of Android studio or ./gradlew build from command line

Comment: Do you want to automatically build ':mymodule', when you run ./gradlew build, but dont want to include module in app build.gradle ?

Comment: yes @BABASHANKER

Comment: mymodule would still build automatically, without including it in the app build.gradle file. Only thing required is to mention ':mymodule' in settings.gradle and you are doing that. Can you share your gradle file ?

Comment: Only thing required is to mention ':mymodule' in settings.gradle but still on click of Run/green Play icon its not generating the any output file in build folder of :mymodule

Comment: @Basha when i am using MyProject->Tasks-> build->build its generating the output files in ':app' and ':mymodule' . Also when you will select the build option in toolbar and click on Make Project that time only selected variant of ':app' and ':mymodule' output file will be generated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200099/discussion-between-naval-kishor-jha-and-basha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirement of automatically building the library project("mymodule" in your case) without including it in the app module build.gradle file, when we press "Run/green Play " icon can be achieved with below approach.

Generally Run icon will be configured for single configuration. This is not at project scope, it is at module scope. Because of this reason, when you press icon, "mymodule" is not built, whereas if you invoke 
1. gradlew build from command line 
2. Sync Project
3. click on Make Project

both the modules(app & mymodule) are built.

To achieve your requirement, we have to edit the existing app configuration in Android studio to build the "mymodule" lib project.

1. Add below task in the app build.gradle

> ```
> task buildModule(type: GradleBuild) {
>     buildFile = '../mymodule/build.gradle'
>     tasks = ['build']
> }
> ```

2. Click on edit configuration in Toolbar

[image]

3. Click on Plus symbol present under "Before launch section", and select the row with "android" icon.

[image]

4. After selecting, a prompt appears and in the prompt, enter ":app:buildModule" and press "OK"

[image]

5. Final UI will be

   [image]
6. Apply the changes and press the "Run" icon, the way you are trying before. This will build "mymodule" automatically.

Comment: Thanks, @Basha  your soln made a great help to me. I have voted up.

Comment: @NavalKishorJha If this had solved your query, mark it as answered, this will help others to consider this solution.